# How to handle escape characters (backslash) in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

while executing the API's using jmeter tool in the response i get some value as '1K\/vyEh'.
while storing this value in the variable it is observed that the backslash does not get stored in the variable resulting in saving the value as '1K/vyEh'
I need guidance of how to save the value as is in the variable

Comment: Since this is a java based product, have you tried double backslash?

Comment: Is there any code involved that you could share? This would help other to reproduce your problem and provide help

Answer (score 0):

There are too many "unknowns" in your question so unfortunately it is not possible to provide a comprehensive answer without seeing:

- at least partial (better full) response
- and the way you're storing the value into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

Here is a quick demo that in theory it is possible:

[image]

The demo assumes:

- [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide/)
- [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)
- [Groovy language](https://groovy-lang.org/) and [regular expressions](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-pattern-matching)